# How to Debug Angular 5 using ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I created a ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio 2017 following the VS available template with Angular 5.

After that I've configured my tsconfig.json : 
[image: Description]

And in Startup.cs I added Spa configuration:

```
 app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
```

The application is working fine using Google Chrome, but I am not able to perform any debugging operations directly in Visual Studio 2017 IDE for the Angular 5 Client app. For example:
[image]

As you can see the breakpoint is not available in this case. What is the approach in this case ?

Comment: I'm curious if this is even possible.  UseAngularCliServer runs a seperate Angular server at port 4200 and sends requests to it.  Maybe there is a way to specify debugging on a particular port?